# Missing binary operator before token "long"

Tags: c++, arduino, freertos, microchip

I'm trying to implement FreeRTOS on my Arduino ATmega2560, and during this process, I came across 2 errors that I don't understand. And don't know how to fix. hopefully someone here does. The first error is `missing binary operator before token "long"`.

The error points to the following line in FreeRTOSConfig.h:

```
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ ((unsigned long) 16000000)
```

And here is the output of the build:

```
C:\Projects\src\config\FreeRTOSConfig.h(36,39): error: missing binary operator before token "long"
     #define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ ((unsigned long) 16000000)
                                           ^
```

This define is only used in `port.c` which has another error that I haven't been able to fix. This error comes from the auto-generated makefile. Not sure if these 2 errors are connected, but better add it here if someone knows how to fix it. The error is:

```
recipe for target 'src/Core/FreeRTOS/port.o' failed
```

And this is what I find in the Makefile:

```
src/Core/FreeRTOS/port.o: ../src/Core/FreeRTOS/port.c
@echo Building file: $<
@echo Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 5.4.0
$(QUOTE)C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe$(QUOTE)  -x c -DDEBUG -DBOARD=USER_BOARD  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\include" -I"../src/ASF/common/boards/user_board" -I"../src/ASF/common/boards" -I"../src/ASF/mega/utils/preprocessor" -I"../src/ASF/mega/utils" -I"../src/ASF/common/utils" -I"../src" -I"../src/config"  -O1 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g3 -Wall -mmcu=atmega2560 -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\gcc\dev\atmega2560" -c -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wpointer-arith -mrelax -MD -MP -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.o)"   -o "$@" "$<" 
@echo Finished building: $<
```

Comment: The line looks perfectly normal. It is impossible to say anything without wider context.

Comment: What about `#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ  16000000UL` ?

Comment: Add `-save-temps` to the command line options and have a look at the pre-processed output (`*.i` for C, `*.ii` for C++, `*.s` for assembly).

Comment: @datafiddler can you explain why this would work, and "unsigned long" would not? Because with this it does compile correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `missing binary operator before token "long"`

This error occurs when you try to use the macro in a pre-processor directive.  For example, compile the following C++ code:

```cpp
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ ((unsigned long) 16000000)

#if configCPU_CLOCK_HZ > 0x1000
#endif
```

avr-g++ will complain:

```
*.cpp:1:39: error: missing binary operator before token "long"
 #define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ ((unsigned long) 16000000)
                                       ^
*.cpp:3:5: note: in expansion of macro 'configCPU_CLOCK_HZ'
 #if configCPU_CLOCK_HZ > 0x1000
     ^
```

So the problem is very likely that `configCPU_CLOCK_HZ` is used in a pre-processor directive like above, but `configCPU_CLOCK_HZ` is not appropriate for such usage.

Yet another problem is that the environment that you are using drops a part of the diagnostics.

`16000000` is already of type `long` because it doesn't fit in `int`, which is 16-bit type in avr-gcc.  So in most cases you can just use plain `16000000`.

If you want something that can be used in preprocessor directives, you can use
`16000000ul`.  Moreover, C99's `stdint.h` provides macros that yield constants of bit-widths that can be used in preprocessor macros like

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ UINT32_C(16000000)
```

which will expand to an unsigned 32-bit type. Notice however, that older versions of AVR-LibC had a bug with these macros: It just used casts which does not comply to the language standard, which states that `[U]INTXX_C` must be usable in pre-processor macros.